# Configuring DNS for a website in Linode

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

It's a very basic question, but I've tried everything, I've read many articles, and even then, I'm still lost, I don't know what's wrong.

I already made a configuration that worked using a free domain.

But I need to use a paid domain that I bought at Registro BR.

I configured DNS on Linode as below:

[image: first]

In type A record I put my machine's ip in Linode

[image: second]

And in RegistroBR I put the Linode NameServers:

[image: third]

I followed the Linode manual and I think I understand it, these are the necessary steps and Its needed to wait 24 hours, I did this and my domain still doesn't find anything.

Comment: Is that the real domain that you're using, superdominio.com.br?

Comment: @Stuggi, no. I changed the original only to use in the example.